# inline SVG breaks HTML page

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, svg

I just tried to render a QR Code using an inline SVG (created by         [phpqrcode](https://github.com/t0k4rt/phpqrcode/)). After removing the doctype, which is generated automatically, I tried to view the page.

It was simply broken:

[image: Firefox Screenshot]

The `Register` you can see on the picture should be in the title.

I also tried in Chrome but there was no difference.

I think the problem is the code or some kind of syntax error.

The code I used is exactly the code below.

I am using Firefox 36.0 on Gentoo GNU/Linux.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="87" height="87" viewBox="0 0 87 87">
<desc></desc>
<rect width="87" height="87" fill="#ffffff" cx="0" cy="0" />
<defs>
    <rect id="p" width="3" height="3" />
</defs>
<g fill="#000000">
    <use x="12" y="12" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="15" y="12" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="18" y="12" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="21" y="12" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="24" y="12" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="27" y="12" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="30" y="12" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="36" y="12" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="39" y="12" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="42" y="12" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="45" y="12" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="48" y="12" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="54" y="12" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="57" y="12" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="60" y="12" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="63" y="12" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="66" y="12" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="69" y="12" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="72" y="12" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="12" y="15" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="30" y="15" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="36" y="15" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="42" y="15" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="48" y="15" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="54" y="15" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="72" y="15" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="12" y="18" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="18" y="18" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="21" y="18" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="24" y="18" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="30" y="18" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="36" y="18" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="54" y="18" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="60" y="18" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="63" y="18" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="66" y="18" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="72" y="18" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="12" y="21" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="18" y="21" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="21" y="21" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="24" y="21" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="30" y="21" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="36" y="21" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="39" y="21" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="42" y="21" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="45" y="21" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="54" y="21" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="60" y="21" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="63" y="21" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="66" y="21" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="72" y="21" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="12" y="24" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="18" y="24" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="21" y="24" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="24" y="24" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="30" y="24" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="48" y="24" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="54" y="24" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="60" y="24" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="63" y="24" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="66" y="24" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="72" y="24" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="12" y="27" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="30" y="27" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="36" y="27" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="39" y="27" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="45" y="27" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="54" y="27" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="72" y="27" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="12" y="30" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="15" y="30" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="18" y="30" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="21" y="30" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="24" y="30" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="27" y="30" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="30" y="30" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="36" y="30" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="42" y="30" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="48" y="30" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="54" y="30" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="57" y="30" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="60" y="30" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="63" y="30" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="66" y="30" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="69" y="30" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="72" y="30" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="39" y="33" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="42" y="33" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="45" y="33" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="48" y="33" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="12" y="36" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="15" y="36" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="24" y="36" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="27" y="36" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="30" y="36" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="39" y="36" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="45" y="36" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="57" y="36" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="63" y="36" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="66" y="36" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="69" y="36" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="72" y="36" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="18" y="39" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="21" y="39" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="33" y="39" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="39" y="39" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="45" y="39" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="48" y="39" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="54" y="39" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="57" y="39" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="60" y="39" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="66" y="39" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="12" y="42" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="15" y="42" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="18" y="42" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="30" y="42" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="39" y="42" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="42" y="42" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="45" y="42" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="60" y="42" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="63" y="42" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="66" y="42" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="69" y="42" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="15" y="45" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="18" y="45" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="24" y="45" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="33" y="45" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="36" y="45" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="42" y="45" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="51" y="45" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="57" y="45" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="69" y="45" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="15" y="48" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="21" y="48" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="24" y="48" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="27" y="48" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="30" y="48" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="36" y="48" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="39" y="48" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="42" y="48" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="48" y="48" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="57" y="48" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="60" y="48" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="69" y="48" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="72" y="48" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="36" y="51" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="48" y="51" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="51" y="51" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="54" y="51" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="60" y="51" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="63" y="51" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="66" y="51" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="69" y="51" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="12" y="54" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="15" y="54" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="18" y="54" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="21" y="54" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="24" y="54" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="27" y="54" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="30" y="54" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="42" y="54" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="48" y="54" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="51" y="54" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="54" y="54" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="60" y="54" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="66" y="54" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="69" y="54" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="12" y="57" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="30" y="57" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="36" y="57" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="45" y="57" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="48" y="57" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="60" y="57" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="69" y="57" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="12" y="60" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="18" y="60" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="21" y="60" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="24" y="60" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="30" y="60" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="36" y="60" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="39" y="60" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="45" y="60" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="51" y="60" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="54" y="60" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="57" y="60" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="63" y="60" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="69" y="60" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="12" y="63" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="18" y="63" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="21" y="63" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="24" y="63" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="30" y="63" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="39" y="63" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="42" y="63" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="45" y="63" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="48" y="63" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="60" y="63" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="63" y="63" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="66" y="63" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="69" y="63" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="72" y="63" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="12" y="66" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="18" y="66" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="21" y="66" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="24" y="66" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="30" y="66" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="39" y="66" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="42" y="66" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="45" y="66" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="54" y="66" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="60" y="66" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="12" y="69" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="30" y="69" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="36" y="69" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="39" y="69" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="42" y="69" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="51" y="69" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="54" y="69" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="60" y="69" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="12" y="72" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="15" y="72" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="18" y="72" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="21" y="72" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="24" y="72" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="27" y="72" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="30" y="72" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="36" y="72" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="42" y="72" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="48" y="72" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="51" y="72" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="54" y="72" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="57" y="72" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="60" y="72" xlink:href="#p" />
    <use x="72" y="72" xlink:href="#p" />
</g>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works fine for me on Firefox, the title is displayed in the tab as I would expect and not on the page. Try safe-mode and/or a new profile.

Comment: What do you mean displayed in the title? The `<title>` tag won't show in your html content, but will be the title of the page. Are you trying to make a favicon?

Comment: Code renders fine in Chrome, FF and Safari. Must have something else going on..

Comment: @dwreck08 The `<title>` from the source code shows as text inside the body.

Comment: @dwreck08 No, I am not trying to make a favicon, I am trying to create an TOTP login at the moment and I need the QR-Code rendered in the body, without saving it to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it.

The problem was the `header` set by PHP in [qrvect.php](https://github.com/t0k4rt/phpqrcode/blob/f0567ce717fa1172cb66c48ebae017a094de64b1/qrvect.php) on line 145.
The Content-Type was not HTML anymore, so Firefox tried to parse the file as SVG.

Thank you very much for your help!